17th/ 18th CE Sailing times to various countries from Argentina
Suppose one had a 17th/ 18th century type sail ship. How long would it take (on average, in appropriate seasons) to sail from/ to Buenos Aires to

Washington DC
Portugal
South Africa
Kerala, India
Australia

Purpose
Not a Homework question!
After fossil fuels and industrial materials become scarce,
we'll be left with something like 17th CE type sailing ships.
So, wondering what travel times would look like if people were in Argentina.
19th CE had fast clippers - but most ships wouldn't be like that.
Prior research

In 1492 it took Columbus two months to cross the Atlantic. In the 18th and 19th century, it still took on average six weeks. If weather conditions were bad, it could take up to three months.
https://improvesailing.com/questions/sail-atlantic

That link also has ocean currents map.
Sailing seasons map:


As your prior research notes sailing times are highly dependent on the weather. Why limit it to 17th Century ships and not 18th or 19th?

Thanks - edited question for clarity.
19th CE had fast clippers - but most ships wouldn't be like that.

I'm not sure that looking at historic sailing times would tell you much about potential sailing times in the future. We know a lot more about naval architecture and ocean sciences now than we did in the 17th century and it's unlikely that modern designs would resemble ships from that period.

@KillingTime: A specific example is that, with the aid of modern aerodynamic understanding, it is now possible to point square riggers significantly higher into the wind with only modest adjustment of the sails from 17th-19th century practice.

@KillingTime But the main question is still answerable here.

If you are curious, Seville-Buenos Aires (which could work for Portugal) took more than 4 months in 1697 (https://www.academia.edu/70311805/Los_viajes_de_Europa_a_Buenos_Aires_seg%C3%BAn_las_cr%C3%B3nicas_de_los_jesuitas_de_los_siglos_XVII_y_XVIII)
